# Update XML Attributes in a XSLT For-Loop

Tags: xml, xslt

In my Souce XML i want to reassign all the Instance ID from numbers 1 to onwards (till there exixtance).
I want to update Apple,Mango,Banana InstanceId's with above values under Profile element.
Here i will ignore Profile `InstanceID` level occurance.
As i am new to XSLT any points will be appreacible.
In below example i have used the XSLT , but it replace all the occurance with 1.

```
<Root>
    <Properties>
        <Props></Props>
        <Input>
        </Input>
        <Profile InstanceID ="4" ObjectID="XYZ"> <!-- no need to update these instanceID -->
            <foo>Profile 1</foo>
            <Apple InstanceID="26" ObjectID="ABC" Type="103"></Apple>
            <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="DEF" Type="103"></Mango>
            <Mango InstanceID="27" ObjectID="GHI" Type="103"></Mango>
            <Banana InstanceID="29" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana>
            </Profile>
    </Properties>

    <Properties>
    <Props></Props>
    <Input></Input>
        <Profile InstanceID ="4" ObjectID="XYZ"> <!-- no need to update these instanceID -->
            <foo>Profile 1</foo>
            <Apple InstanceID="33" ObjectID="MNO" Type="103"></Apple>
            <Mango InstanceID="25" ObjectID="PQR" Type="103"></Mango>
            <Mango InstanceID="2" ObjectID="EFG" Type="103"></Mango>
            <Mango InstanceID="28" ObjectID="EFG123" Type="103"></Mango>
            <Banana InstanceID="31" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana>
        </Profile>
    </Properties>
</Root>
```

Below is the XSLT i used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="counter1" select="0"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Profile/*/@InstanceID">
        <xsl:attribute name="InstanceID">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And these is Output/Transformed XML

```
<Root>
    <Properties>
        <Props></Props>
        <Input>
        </Input>
        <Profile InstanceID ="4" ObjectID="XYZ"> <!-- no need to update these instanceID -->
        <foo>Profile 1</foo>
        <Apple InstanceID="1" ObjectID="ABC" Type="103"></Apple> <!-- Correct -->
        <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="DEF" Type="103"></Mango> <!-- Expected val = 2 -->
        <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="GHI" Type="103"></Mango> <!-- Expected val = 3 -->
        <Banana InstanceID="1" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana> <!-- Expected val = 4 -->
        </Profile>
    </Properties>    
    <Properties>
        <Props></Props>
        <Input></Input>
        <Profile InstanceID ="4" ObjectID="XYZ"> <!-- no need to update these instanceID -->
        <foo>Profile 1</foo>
        <Apple InstanceID="1" ObjectID="MNO" Type="103"></Apple> <!-- Correct -->
        <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="PQR" Type="103"></Mango> <!-- Expected val = 2 -->
        <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="EFG" Type="103"></Mango> <!-- Expected val = 3 -->
        <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="EFG123" Type="103"></Mango> <!-- Expected val = 4 -->
        <Banana InstanceID="1" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana> <!-- Expected val = 5 -->
        </Profile>
    </Properties>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
```

This line is not displaying the `position()` of the fruit-element but the position of the attribute `@InstanceID` (wich is, naturally, always 1).

To fix this you must not use `position()` but count all preceding siblings *of the parent* that contain the `@InstanceID` attribute:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*[@InstanceID]) + 1" />
```

Comment: "the position of the attribute @InstanceID (wich is, naturally, always 1).". Actually since there are three attributes and the order is undefined, the position() here could equally be 2 or 3.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it was the case. "always 1" was meant more figuratively, showing that it has nothing to do with the position of the element the attribute is in.

Comment: Thanks Nils that really worked. Can you suggest how to apply a condition that the above logic of reassigning the instance id should work only if atleast one instanceid in one set is greater than 25 ?

Comment: Please open a new question for that.

Comment: Hi Nils , please find the link with new question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516831/update-xml-attributes-based-on-specific-attribute-value