# Update XML Attributes based on specific attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

In my Source XML i am reassigning all the Instance ID from numbers 1 to onwards (till there existence). I am updating Apple, Mango, Banana InstanceId's with above values under Profile element. Here i ignore Profile InstanceID level occurrence. My requirement is to trigger these xslt code only when at least one instance id in a given set of "Profile" is greater than 25.

```
<Root>
  <Properties>
    <Props></Props>
    <Input></Input>
    <Profile InstanceID="4" ObjectID="XYZ">
      <foo>Profile 1</foo><!-- Need to update these set as atleast one instanceID is greater than 25 -->
      <Apple InstanceID="26" ObjectID="ABC" Type="103"></Apple>
      <Mango InstanceID="1" ObjectID="DEF" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Mango InstanceID="27" ObjectID="GHI" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Banana InstanceID="29" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana>
    </Profile>
  </Properties>
  <Properties>
    <Props></Props>
    <Input></Input>
    <Profile InstanceID="4" ObjectID="XYZ">
      <foo>Profile 1</foo><!-- no need to update these set as no instanceID is greater than 25 -->
      <Apple InstanceID="21" ObjectID="MNO" Type="103"></Apple>
      <Mango InstanceID="21" ObjectID="PQR" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Mango InstanceID="23" ObjectID="EFG" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Mango InstanceID="24" ObjectID="EFG123" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Banana InstanceID="25" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana>
    </Profile>
  </Properties>
</Root>
```

Below is the XSLT i used

```
# XSLT #
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
        exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Profile/*/@InstanceID">
    <xsl:attribute name="InstanceID">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*[@InstanceID]) + 1" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And these is Output/Transformed XML

```
# Transformed XML #
<Root>
  <Properties>
    <Props></Props>
    <Input></Input>
    <Profile InstanceID="4" ObjectID="XYZ"><!-- no need to update these instanceID -->
      <foo>Profile 1</foo>
      <Apple InstanceID="1" ObjectID="ABC" Type="103"></Apple>
      <Mango InstanceID="2" ObjectID="DEF" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Mango InstanceID="3" ObjectID="GHI" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Banana InstanceID="4" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana>
    </Profile>
  </Properties>
  <Properties>
    <Props></Props>
    <Input></Input>
    <Profile InstanceID="4" ObjectID="XYZ"><!-- no need to update these instanceID -->
      <foo>Profile 1</foo>
      <Apple InstanceID="1" ObjectID="MNO" Type="103"></Apple>
      <Mango InstanceID="2" ObjectID="PQR" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Mango InstanceID="3" ObjectID="EFG" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Mango InstanceID="4" ObjectID="EFG123" Type="103"></Mango>
      <Banana InstanceID="5" ObjectID="GHI1" Type="103"></Banana>
    </Profile>
  </Properties>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is to trigger these xslt code only when at least one instance id in a given set of "Profile" is greater than 25

You simply need to make your `Profile/*/@InstanceID` template slightly more specific.  At the moment it applies to `InstanceID` attributes on child elements of *all* `Profile` elements, you need to add a predicate at the `Profile` level to restrict it to certain profiles only:

```
<xsl:template match="Profile[*/@InstanceID &gt; 25]/*/@InstanceID">
```

This works because a comparison operator where one side is a node set is true if *any* of the nodes in the set satisfy the required condition, so in this case if *any* of the child elements has an `InstanceID` greater than 25.